# Open a standard record page in edit mode

Tags: apex, visualforce

It's very easy open the detail page of a new record created in a custom controller of a visual force page.

Example code:

```
public PageReference save() {

        PageReference acctPage = new PageReference('/' + Influencer.id);
        acctPage.setRedirect(true);
        return acctPage;
    }
```

But i would like to be able to open the page of the new record in edit mode. How to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you have to do is attend `'/e'` (edit). Adding the `retURL` parameter will take an url to which the page should navigate on `save` and `cancel` actions. If you don't add this the page will default to going to the homepage.

```
PageReference acctPage = new PageReference('/'+ID+'/e?retURL=%2Fa'+ID);
```

will do what you want. Not sure if there are more dynamic ways to get that.

Comment: You can also do this:

    `public PageReference save() {
        return new ApexPages.StandardController(Influencer).edit();
    }`

This has the advantage of using the standard utility that forms the correct link for you; if salesforce.com changes their behavior later, this code will still get the correct url.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Samuel return new ApexPages.StandardController(Influencer).edit(); this one works but after landing in edit mode cancel and save options are not working. But this one is the solution to edit the record from apex.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. Do note that this site isn't built for back-and-forth discussion. Also, be aware that you're replying to a question that's nearly 11 years old (and it seems you're trying to reply to sfdcfox, not Samuel). URL-hacking like this doesn't work so well in the current UI (lightning experience) If you have a different question, you should create your own question. You can link back to this question to help provide some context.